# Is a subalgebra of a normed algebra again a normed algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Suppose that $(A,\parallel\cdot\parallel)$ is a normed algebra (with or without an identity) and $B\subseteq A$ is a subalgebra of $A$. It is said in my textbook that $B$, together with the induced norm, is also a normed algebra.

However, it is assumed that the norm of the identity in a unital normed algebra is $1$. If $B$ happens to contain an identity $\mathbf{1}_B$, then in order for $B$ to become a normed algebra, we need to show that $\parallel\mathbf{1}_B\parallel=1$. Since $\mathbf{1}_B$ is not necessarily the identity in $A$, it is not guaranteed that $\parallel\mathbf{1}_B\parallel=1$. So I think $B$ may not also be a normed algebra.

Any comments on this issue?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Let $M_2$ be the algebra of all 2×2 matrices over the reals, and let $\parallel\cdot\parallel$ be the norm on it defined by $\parallel A\parallel=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\parallel A\parallel_F$, where $\parallel\cdot\parallel_F$ is the Frobenius norm. The norm $\parallel\cdot\parallel$ makes $M_2$ a unital normed algebra with identity $I$. The 2×2 matrices for which all entries are zero, except for the first one on the diagonal, form a subalgebra. This subalgebra is not a normed algebra since the norm of its identity (1,0,/0,0) is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, not $1$. Am I correct?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez If this example makes sense, then the statement "a subalgebra of a normed algebra is a normed algebra" is not correct in general. Am I right?

Comment: Two questions about definitions:  Does your textbook's definition of a normed algebra require that $\|ab\|\le\|a\|\,\|b\|$ for all $a,b\in A$? Does your textbook define a subalgebra to contain the unit of the larger algebra?

Comment: @Aweygan 1)Yes, the norm is submultiplicative; 2)No. A subalgebra is a subspace closed under multiplication.

Comment: Could you please share the author/title of the textbook?

Comment: @Aweygan Oh, it's actually not a textbook but a set of lecture notes on C* algebra. See this link (the statement is right after definition 1.5): https://math.dartmouth.edu/~dana/bookspapers/cstar.pdf

Comment: I see, thanks for sharing!  I have updated my answer to hopefully clarify the issue

Answer (score 0):

This is a subtle point, one that the author barely mentions, but a **unital normed algebra** is more than just a normed algebra with a unit.
A unital normed algebra is a normed algebra $(A,\|\cdot\|)$ with a unit $1_A\in A$ such that $\|1_A\|=1$.
While a subalgebra of a normed algebra is itself a normed algebra, it is not true that a unital subalgebra of a unital normed algebra is itself a unital normed algebra

Indeed, suppose $(A,\|\cdot\|)$ is a unital normed algebra containing an idempotent $e$ with $\|e\|>1$, and let $B=eAe$.  Then $B$ is a subalgebra of $A$, with unit $e$, but it is not a normed algebra with the norm induced by $A$, as the unit of $B$ does not have norm one.